# Connection timeout. No DDP heartbeat received

Tags: meteor, ddp

I'm trying to upload over 5,000 comments from a CSV and then insert them into a collection.

I get the following:

```
all done dfae22fc33f08cde515ac7452729cf4921d63ebe.js:24
insert failed: MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error index: ag5Uriwu.comments.$_id_  dup key: { : "SuvPB3frrkLs8nErv" } dfae22fc33f08cde515ac7452729cf4921d63ebe.js:1
Connection timeout. No DDP heartbeat received.
```

The script at hand:

```
  'click .importComments': function(e) {
    var $self = $(e.target);

    $self.text("Importing...");
    $("#commentsCSV").parse({
      worker: true,
      config: {
        step: function(row) {
          var data = row.data;
          for (var key in data) {
            var obj = data[key];

            post = Posts.findOne({legacyId: obj[1]});

            var comment = {
              // attributes here
            };

            Comments.insert(comment);
            Posts.update(comment.postId, {
              $inc: { commentsCount: 1 },
            });
          }
          $self.text("Import Comments");
        },
        complete: function(results, file) {
          console.log("all done");
        }
      }
    });
  }
```

How can I make this work without blowing up with the connection timeout errors?

Locally it seems to work decently but on production (modulus.io) it ends pretty abruptly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem here is not to do with DDP but with MongoDB. The DDP connection is timing out due to the MongoDB error.

You're getting a duplicate key error on the `_id` field. The `_id` field is automatically indexed by MongoDB and it is a unique index so the same value cannot appear twice in the same collection.

The CSV you're uploading likely has its own `_id` fields in it meaning Mongo is not generating its own binary fields (which guarantee uniqueness).

So I'd recommend removing the `_id` field from the CSV if it exists.

You can also try  using the following package: http://atmospherejs.com/package/csv-to-collection